# Can you use links when sending a message from Careers?

Tags: support, tags, hyperlinks, jobs

I would like to send some links to a potential employee/employer. We have an ongoing message thread going. It is not clear if Markdown like `[link text](http://link)` will work in there, or if they will just show up as is.

Can I use `[link text](http://link)` or do I have to send the hyperlink as text?

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't/don't need to mark up hyperlinks in this way. You can only use plain text in messages, but URLs will automatically be clickable for the recipient.

For example if you type `My link http://google.com` it will be rendered like this:

[image: Link in a message]